# Getters in recursive class with pointers to other instances of the class

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, recursion, tree

For a school project, I need to build a BinarySearchTree for a tuple of index and value of type T and I decided to make it using left and right child pointers (to other instances but bear with me).

To make the class a bit more realistic and readable, I built 3 different classes: Tree, BinaryTree, and BinarySearchTree with inheritance.

I declared the getter and the setter of the left and right children in the BinaryTree class and the class looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class ArbreBinaire : public Arbre<T>
{
private:
  ArbreBinaire<T>* _leftChild;
  ArbreBinaire<T>* _rightChild;

public:
  ArbreBinaire(lu index = 0, T element = T(0), ArbreBinaire<T>* lchild = nullptr, ArbreBinaire<T>* rchild = nullptr) :
    Arbre<T>(index, element), _leftChild(lchild), _rightChild(rchild) {};

  virtual ArbreBinaire<T>* getLC() const { return _leftChild; }
  virtual ArbreBinaire<T>* getRC() const { return _rightChild;}

  void setLC(ArbreBinaire<T>* lc) {  _leftChild = lc; lc->setParent(this); }
  void setRC(ArbreBinaire<T>* rc) { _rightChild = rc; rc->setParent(this); }


  virtual ~ArbreBinaire() = default;
};
```

And in my BinarySearchTree, in a few places I need to go through my tree (to insert or search for exemple).
So here comes finally my question: What is the best way to get the left child of my object, which is of type BinarySearchTree and to keep the continuity (BST that has BST left child and BST right child)

I thought of multiple options:

1. virtual getter and setter and redefining it in every derived class but there are 2 other "problems" with that solution.
2. Should I have 2 other members in my BST, which would be of type BST* and basically point to the same object than the ones in my BinaryTree ?

   1. Should I just redefine my getters to return a dynamic_cast version like this : `BST<T>* getLC() { return dynamic_cast<BST<T>*> (this->BinaryTree::getLC()) }` ?
   2. Putting all my members, getters and setters in my BST class (but that goes opposite to the definition of a BinaryTree, the base class : a BinaryTree with no children is not a BinaryTree)

3.Just casting every time i need to get my left or right child
4.Casting everytime i need to use a method in BST (derived class) ?
5. Any other suggestions?

Comment: 5. Factor out the node type from the tree types. The nodes hold data, the trees maintain the structure.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't see how that could solve the problem, can you explain a bit more ? My Node itself contains the index and the value (of type T) and is the only member of my class Tree (the base class of BinaryTree)